# Connecting database to listbox

Tags: c#, wpf, mongodb

Im at the moment learning WPF, C# And MongoDB.
I want to go to a database and show my _Id into a listview.
So i have my main window with a button, when i click the button a popup windows comes out and shows the list with all my "_id" inside the database.
I dont know how to do that, i keep struggling. 
Here it is:

ConnectionServer

```
public partial class ConnectionServers : UserControl
{
    public  List<TextBlock> serverId { get;set; }

    public ObservableCollection<ConnectionServers> serversList  { get; set;  }

    public String svList { get; set; }

    public ConnectionServers()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

XML

```
    <Grid>
    <ListBox x:Name="listBoxServers" Grid.Row="1" BorderThickness="0" 
     ItemsSource="{Binding serversList}">
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <TextBlock x:Name="textBlockServersId" Text="{Binding 
    serverId}"/>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ListBox>
</Grid>
```

MainWindow

```
  private ObservableCollection<ConnectionServers> listOfServers;

     private  async void dataBaseMongoAsync(string collectionName)
    {

        var client = new MongoClient("mongodb://XXXXXXXX");
        var db = client.GetDatabase("Project");

        var collection = db.GetCollection<BsonDocument>(collectionName);


        await collection.Find(new BsonDocument()).ForEachAsync(_id => ListOfServers.Add(new ConnectionServers() { serversList = _id }));


    }



private void onConnect_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {

        ConnectionServers availableServers = new ConnectionServers();

        Window serversList = new Window
        {
            Title = "Server List",
            Content = availableServers,
            Height = 300,
            Width = 350,
            Background = FindResource("WindowBackground") as Brush,
            ResizeMode = ResizeMode.NoResize
        };

        serversList.ShowDialog();

    }
```

EDIT: I can't understand the problem. What i was thinking is when i do this:

```
 await collection.Find(new BsonDocument()).ForEachAsync(_id => ListOfServers.Add(new ConnectionServers() { serversList = _id }));~
```

instead of ListOfServers, serversList ( but i can't acess it from here ). My logic was bind a texblock to a list, then increment to the list the results.

Comment: Why do you think you need a UserControl? Start with a ListBox in the MainWindow or some other Window. If that works, take the next step.

Comment: Where are you populating the serversList collection?

Comment: Your listbox is binded to ObservableCollection "serversList". And where have you added values into it?

Comment: You're right, it  changed it from UserControl to Window. But i still don't know how to pass data from that class to the MainWindow one. My logic was something like  await collection.Find(new BsonDocument()).ForEachAsync(_id => ListOfServers.Add(new ConnectionServers() { serversList = _id })); and where is ListOfServices.Add put servversList.Add, but i can't acess it. What am i missing i can't understand.

Comment: @Clemens I use UserControl so i can make a popup window. If i go for Window tag it does not work

Answer (score 0):

Unless you're working with a framework that handles the PropertyChanged events, you'd need to raise it by yourself. ie:

```
private List<Text> _servers;
public List<Text servers
{
get { return _servers;}
set { _servers = value;
OnPropertyChanged(nameof(servers));}}
```

a few other notes:

1. You're not using a ViewModel nor are you defining a DataContext. You'd have to set the source to itself on the bindings or just add `DataContext = this;` in the constructor of the user control.
   **Granted using the UserControl to be it's own VM like this is a pretty bad design in the first place- see Clemens' comment below**
2. I dont see a reason for a List of TextBlocks, it's bad practice anyway. You want to seperate the DATA from the UI- and then use bindings to displayed said data in the ui
3. You need to Bind to Title (within the Listbox, each item template would have it's Datacontext set to the relevant item/class in the list)

Comment: A UserControl should never explicitly set its DataContext. Doing so will later break all DataContext-based Bindings of its dependency properties. It shouldn't even have something like an own "private" view model. It should instead expose dependency properties and use RelativeSource Bindings to those properties in its own XAML.

Comment: The logic i followed is that i want a list of items. The items should be displayed in TextBlock. So what should i do? Creat a ListBox, Binding it, and then?
Tyvm in advance.

Comment: Well, you have a ListBox with an item template that defines a TextBlock already, with a binding on the Text property as well. All you need is a list of strings which you'd bind as the itemSource and then 'Text="{Binding }"' will do the trick of binding each string in the list to the textblock in the item template. If you'd rather have a list of some class items, which has a server id property, then you'd do something like- Text="{Binding 
    serverIdProperty}"

Answer (score 0):

The text box in your item template is bound to the serverId list, which isn't used elsewhere.

Instead it should bind to the Id propery of a server, as each item in the list box will be one of the servers from the serversList ObservableCollection, because that's what the ItemSource it bound to.

When debugging binding problems, it helps to check for debug messages in VisualStudio's Output window, as you'll often get a helpful (if long and complex) message.